# How do you set up OpenCV with QT in OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv, osx-snow-leopard

I want to use the new C++ OpenCV interface to create Qt applications in Qt Creator on OS X Snow Leopard.  How can I do this?  Good explanations of this are very hard to come by online.

Comment: First of all, welcome to stackoverflow.  Next, to the business side of things -- it may be worth rephrasing your question in a more specific way.  Right now, it just sounds like you're asking people to write (or find) a HOWTO for you.  What have you actually tried?  What doesn't work as you expected?

Comment: Agreed witg misha. Moreover you scared the * out of me. I want to do exactly this, this weekend, and you made me believe it might have been a terrible path to take. Anyhow: first install xcode, then you have make and gcc, then install macports, then you have port, then: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port . Morover, the qt-website offers an pkg, which is probably just click and play (You could have at least tried this, right ;)). One problem you may encounter is that xcode isn't (easily) available to snow leopard anymore, my solution was to spend some money on lion. GL!

Comment: btw, if I'm done, I will post an answer if not already done. Feel free to poke me if I forget.

Comment: Since I answered the question you felt worth asking with something that took me some time to document and write down in 2 days, could you please either add a comment on what you do not understand or disagree with, or accept it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this, and it was fairly easy. You can download QtSDK from the qt-website as a dmg, installing that is just click-and-play.

After this I used MacPorts, MacPorts is a package-manager (like aptitude, portage, pacman, etc) for osx. http://www.macports.org/, download it, and again: click-and-play.

To use MacPorts, you first need tools like make and gcc/g++ to work. These are included in the package xcode (which is in the apple store). Of course, these tools are as important as a cpu to a developer. You would want them in the first place.

After installing xcode, make/g++/gcc are on your system, yet they are not in your path. In a terminal, the commands won't exist. To fix this, open the xcode ide (If I am allowed to call it an ide, am I?). Then goto XCode (lop left screen)-> Preferences -> Downloads. There you can install the 'Command Line Tools', do this.

Then make should be there. Use a terminal to verify. Just typing make will probably message you 'make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.', but not 'command not found'.

Then, to install opencv I installed MacPorts, type 'sudo port install opencv', wait a while and if all went well, you should have opencv. It is installed in /opt/local. Therefore you might need to add these to your .pro-file:

```
CONFIG += MYHOTOSXMACHINE

MYHOTOSXMACHINE {
    INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include/
    LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib/
}
```

So, there you go. Good luck!

PS: I not new to the whole linux/gnu/posix thing, yet I am new to osx. So if there is a cleaner way to do this, feel free to comment.