# Setting up OpenCV in QT on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, opencv

I am trying to set up `OpenCV` to work with `QT` on OSX 10.7.5/MacbookPro 2.5 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo. I've seen a few related question here ([How to link opencv in QtCreator and use Qt library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library?rq=1)  and  [How do you set up OpenCV with QT in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403455/how-do-you-set-up-opencv-with-qt-in-osx/10962312#10962312)) but there isn't much detail. On the QT site and in my web searches all of the information seems to be about Windows or Linux.

---

I've listed what my setup and code is below. When I run the code I am getting an error: `:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Does this mean it's not finding stuff because the paths are wrong or because I may have built openCV for x86_32? Is there a way of checking the latter? I'm not so savvy with parts of the configuration and setup process.

---

**Update 2**

The console output is below - perhaps the error is obvious?

```
02:44:38: Running steps for project RP_openCV_01...
02:44:38: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
02:44:38: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o RP_openCV_01 main.o   -L/usr/local/lib -1ibopencv_core.2.4.6,dylib -1ibopencv_imgproc.2.4.6.dylib -F/Users/rise/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/clang_64/lib -framework QtCore 
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-1ibopencv_core.2.4.6,dylib'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-1ibopencv_imgproc.2.4.6.dylib'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imread(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::waitKey(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RP_openCV_01] Error 1
02:44:38: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project RP_openCV_01 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.2 clang 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

---

What I have so far *(the tl;dr):*

- built and installed the latest version of openCV (2.4.6) from source and tested it with some command line programs.
- installed the latest version of QT (5.1) and am able to run all the examples, etc.
- specified the paths in the project file (below)

> ```
> QT       += core
> QT       -= gui
>
> TARGET = RP_openCV_01
> CONFIG   += console
> CONFIG   -= app_bundle
>
> TEMPLATE = app
> SOURCES += main.cpp
>
> INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include\
> LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
> ```

- tried to specify the path in the project settings (below). I added `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`

[image]

The simple example code in main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main() {

    // read an image
    cv::Mat image= cv::imread("dog.jpg");
    // create image window named "My Image"
    cv::namedWindow("My Image");
    // show the image on window
    cv::imshow("My Image", image);
    // wait key for 5000 ms
    cv::waitKey(5000);

    return 1;
}
```

---

**Update 1**

Another thing I tried based on a tutorial was to specify the libs in the QT profile (as in image below). The tutorial was for Windows though and I didn't know if or how OSX is different. Where in the Windows example it is `-1ibopencv_core246d` I tried it with and without the separating periods but without the "d". Of course the full name of a lib is "libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib" etc.

These sorts of important details always trip me up but it's often assumed in tutorials that one knows this stuff.

```
 LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
     -1ibopencv_core.2.4.6 \
     -1ibopencv_imgproc.2.4.6 \
     -1ibopencv_features2d.2.4.6 \
     -1ibopencv_highgui.2.4.6
```

[image]

Comment: By default, OpenCV 2.4.6 is built for the native architecture (should be x86_64). When you say "run", how do you exactly launch your code? It may be related to the fact that DYLD_LIBRARY__PATH does not contain the path to opencv .dylib files.

Comment: @sansuiso - I am using QTCreator to build and run this. I added an update to my question to explain how I tried to specify the libs to include.

Comment: It used to work for me on 10.8 using [this .pro file](https://gist.github.com/bestimmaa/7033447) but since setting up a new dev machine with 10.9 I get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a naive mistake

The proper declaration is:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
     -lopencv_core \
     -lopencv_imgproc \
     -lopencv_features2d\
     -lopencv_highgui
```

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over the same problem. Here is how I solved it:

As [sansuiso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529514/1141118) already suggested, the problem appears to be the C++-STD-lib you are trying to link against. You are probably trying to link libc++ (LLVM ...) but instead libstdc++ (GNU C++ ...) should be used.

Using the Qt Creator you can add the following to your .pro-file:

```
mac: CONFIG += MAC_CONFIG

MAC_CONFIG {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
    QMAKE_LFLAGS = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
}
```

This answer could also be interesting for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12852913/1141118

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I built openCV separately and was able to get it to link with just the definitions in my answer below.

Comment: `CONFIG  += c++11` seems enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing 2 potential issues here:

1. first one is, on Mac platforms, **depending on the compiler** (clang or gcc) you will not link against the **same stdc++ library** (I ran into this issue while trying to get some static opencv lib working with an iOS project). However, it does not seem to be the case here since you do not have C++ errors, but it's worth checking what compiler you use in each case;
2. second one, **QtCreator** is a **graphical app**. Thus it is not aware of your terminal-session settings. This includes the path to dynamic libraries in `/usr/local`. You can avoid this by different approaches: using a static opencv lib, using `install_tool` to change the path to the library coded in the output binary, or by using the preferences of QtCreator to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to something like `/usr/local/lib` when it runs your program.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to setup Opencv in QT in OSX:

1- Install QT

2- Install OpenCV4

3- Add the following lines in the project file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4\

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
     -lopencv_core \
     -lopencv_imgproc \
     -lopencv_features2d\
     -lopencv_highgui

QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0
```

4- In the Project section, under the Built section, uncheck the following:

```
Add build library search path to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
```

The following links are helpful:

[Dlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509731/dyld-symbol-not-found-cg-jpeg-resync-to-restart)

[Warning Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216273/object-file-was-built-for-newer-osx-version-than-being-linked)