# Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in QtCreator unsing OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, 64-bit

I installed OpenCv via Macports and QT-Creator on my Mac.
I included the header Files both to my Project

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```

Inside the .pro File and configured it like this

> INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include/

```
LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib/
```

I am just using imgread to load an image.
But if i compile i got an error like

> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

So it seems that my configuration is wrong in some way ?
Does anybody know what i am doing wrong ?
Or how do i import and install openCV inside QT under Mac OS 10.7.5 ?

Comment: I had success specifying the specific libs as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17552660/840992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking around in the Internet i found the following Solution :

```
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include

LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib

LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d \
-lopencv_contrib \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_flann \
-lopencv_gpu \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_legacy \
-lopencv_ml \
-lopencv_objdetect \
-lopencv_video
```

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the message

```
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

and select `Show Output (O)`.

You will then see the full message that QtCreator has been hiding.