# Create GUI like Qt using OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

[image]

This is the GUI I created usin Qt. I want to do the same thing using OpenCV. I have read about the new Qt Functions in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html). The thing is, the implementation is not clear, so is there any tutorial or any guide present that implements these functions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don´t do it the other way around and use Qt for GUI and OpenCV for processing and show the processed Image in the Qt Gui? That how i usually do it... the OpenCV Gui is IMHO just for very quick testing GUIs...

Comment: GUI provided by OpenCV is too simple, I think you need to convert cv::Mat to QImage, so OpenCV does the image processing and Qt is in charge displaying the result

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I don't know how to include OpenCV in a Qt application. If there is any tutorial or you know how to do so then please tell me.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage you can then show your image as a QImage in the Qt GUI (in a QLabel for example)

Comment: @Mailerdaimon You also don't know how to add OpenCV to Qt so I can make GUI using Qt and program using OpenCV?

Comment: I just wrote what you need. The point is how to get your image data from OpenCV to Qt format, the rest is programming as usual. I don´t understand what else you need?!

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava - there are a few answers here on SO on how to set up openCV in QT. I did it on OSX but there are links to doing it on windows. It's pretty easy and then you have the whole QT toolkit. See my Q & A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518408/setting-up-opencv-in-qt-on-osx. The gist is build and install openCV and then just link to it.