# Object file was built for newer OSX version than being linked

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gnu-make

I'm getting this error for C++ library I'm using. It uses GNU Automake for building. Which flag(s) I should supply for the `make` command to lower the target build platform to avoid seeing this warning in Xcode project where I'm trying to link against the library?

Answer (score 22):

You need to set the compiler flag `-mmacosx-version-min` to the version number of the SDK you want to build against. I don't use `automake`, but in `cmake` you'd set the variable `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`, and in `qmake` you'd set the variable `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

Comment: If you're having this problem with QtCreator, simply add `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = xx.xx` to your project file, where xx.xx is the version number of the SDK used to compile the library

Comment: Thanks a lot `SET(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 12.0)` worked for me

Answer (score 17):

As cbrnr answered, you have to use -mmacosx-version-min compiler flag. To pass compiler flag through make, you can use CXXFLAGS environment variable:

```
make CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.10" <target or other make params>
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `./configure` for a number of packages the `macosx-version-min` setting defaults to particular OS version - which can lead to the mentioned warning message if that OS version is lower than the `macosx-version-min` version that the linked library was compiled. However, this can be controlled by setting the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` environment variable before running configure e.g.

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.14 ./configure
```