# ld: warning: dylib was built for newer macOS version (11.3) than being linked (11.1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

My situation

- Mac OS Monterey 12.1 (M1, 2020)
- Visual Studio Code v1.64.2

Everytime I try to compile cpp file, the warning below is shown in terminal.

```
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.3) than being linked (11.1)
```

I have no idea how to fix this.
I read [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216273/object-file-was-built-for-newer-osx-version-than-being-linked), and tried the below command, but did not change the situation.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Have you tried checking which version of gcc you've installed? If after updating with `xcode-select --install` you try to uninstall and reinstall gcc. Do you still receive the same error?

What's the output of:

`brew info gcc`

Do you have any updates available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.3` can eliminate the warning.

Comment: It helps me with "export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.0". My warning msg is "ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/lib/libX11.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (12.0) than being linked (11.3)".

Comment: Here's a solution that doesn't fix a specific version: `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$(sw_vers -productVersion)`. This way, you can put this in a sourced shell script and forget about it...